# What are the common algorithm to calculate similarity between zones of images

Tags: image-processing

I have already tried mean squared error and cross correlation, but they don't give me that much of a good result.  I'm doing that for Brain MRI.  Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at how perceptualdiff does it: http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen principal component analysis used to compare separate brain scan images.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5874201

This might be useful, but I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with similarity between sones.